# How to define a json object type in a JacksonDB Mapper for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, jackson, mongo-jackson-mapper

I am building a Play framework Java application with mongodb as the backend.
I am using Jackson DB Mapper to define the model.

One of the models needs to have a field called "filter" with the following value in the Mongodb,

```
"filters" : {
        "nutrients" : "fiber",
        "course" : "starter",
        "cuisine" : "indian",
        "locale" : "india",
        "specialdiet" : "spicy"
    }
```

How do I define this object in Java Jackson DB?

Please forgive my jargon since I am new Jackson DB mapper.